# Port forwarding on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, port, openshift

I recently got a node.js app up and running on my localhost. Basically, there's a client-side app that runs on my xampp installation, and a server.js that the client connects to. I uploaded the server files to OpenShift and tried to run the app, but got an error because the port wasn't forwarded and therefore couldn't even listen.

I need to know how I can forward specific ports and what ports I can bind the server app to.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward the ports using `rhc port-forward` command. rhc is the OpenShift command-line client. It is a ruby gem that you can install using `gem install rhc` command.

Answer (score 0):

you can port forward in opeshift nodejs app using rhc port-forward -a "application name"